# Android: How to post an image on screen

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm new in Android and I am planning to develop a post-it card Android app. After editing one card, the user could post it on the screen, so every time a user unlocks his phone he will see a little card posted on the home screen. So are there any materials and resources I can learn to realize that effect? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can interact with the homescreen through widgets. You can start learning about them here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

You could also start looking into the 2D graphics framework. Here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

There are also a lot of tutorials and examples provided by the community, but if you are new to android I think it will be a long way to accomplish what you just mentioned.

Comment: Thank u very much!! Very helpful to me. It really bothers me when I refer to sth but don't know the exact name in English for it. Could be longer way than I thought but I will keep on working on it~ Thanks again!